# ROP on scanf(%[NUM] s)

Tags: assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering, pwntools

im trying to do a ROP attack using buffer over flow:

```
int main(void)

{
  char str[112];
  
  puts("What is your name? ");

scanf("%129s",str);
  printf("Goodbye %s!\n",str);
  return 0;
}
```

Im trying to buffer over flow the RIP and my offset is 120.
means I can overwrite 120-129.

But it doesnt change my RIP data.
I want to the return function to another hidden function I found.
but there is 129 char limit.
what im doing worng?

[gdb-peda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ER6d.png)

as you can see the RIP reg is 0x0 and not BBBBCCCC